# domain registry with Istio ServiceEntry

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Now I am testing the scenario running apps on Istio.
I cant access to legacy codes, so I cant change request urls.

For that, I made some simple apps.

I am not sure this scenario is available on Istio.

I have two applications(order and customer)
On the order app, there is code calling customer app with url  "http://customer-app:8080/customer".

Now, I want to run two apps on K8S with Istio.
And I don't want to change my code especially calling urls.
(I know I can call each service with service-name.
but I want to make customer service name with "customer-service" not "customer-app")

I find there is a VirtualService which can register MESH_INTERNAL.
I make yaml file like that.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3   
kind: ServiceEntry   
metadata:  
  name: customer-service-entry  
spec:  
  hosts:  
  - http://customer-app:8080  
  location: MESH_INTERNAL  
  ports:  
  - number: 8080  
    name: http  
    protocol: http  
  endpoints:  
  - address: customer-service  
    ports:  
      http: 8080
```

is it possible scenario using virtual domain?

Comment: Could you clarify, where you want to use name "customer-service" insted of "customer-app", inside the cluster or from the outside of it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: customer-app
spec:
  hosts:
  - customer-app
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 8080
    route:
    - destination:
        host: customer-service
        port:
          number: 9080
```

You will also need to define a dummy K8S service for customer-app, so that it's resolvable:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: customer-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
```

Comment: I tested it and it worked. Then, what if the calling url is ip based like http://192.168.xx.xx:8080/customer" instead of http://customer-app:8080/customer", is there a way to treat it?

Comment: I don't see why not, as long as the host can be found, it should work. Acceptable values for a `VirtualService` host is documented [here](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#VirtualService).